# Which is the best way to update VF page input fields using Javascript? Why?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, inputfield, dynamic

I have seen both of these being used to update VF page inputs in Javascript dynamically.

Approach 1:

```
document.getElementById('{!$Component.thePage.theForm.theField}').required = true;
```

Approach 2:

```
document.getElementById('thePage:theForm:theField').required = true;
```

Are there any scenarios that either of them may fail? or better than the other.

Comment: if you add any element between the hierarchy it will fail

Comment: Thanks. Would be interested to know which one is recommended and why, or these are just 2 ways to refer it, out of curiosity why would SF introduce referring Component while javascript already got a way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Since DOM IDs in Visualforce components are dynamically generated in order to ensure IDs are unique, the advantage of using $Component is this will give you the dynamic order and you dont have to manually create it , in the absolute sense as you have created in Approach 2. So if you  have nested tags and in the inner tag you can just reference $Component.idOfElement instead of manually trying to figure out what the ids will be.

In the example below : you can just use {!$Component.theSectionItem} to get j_id0:theForm:thePageBlock:theSection:theSectionItem.

When creating the id for the 'form', VF dynamically named the form id as "j_id0:theForm"

The value for $Component is relative to  where you are calling it from. In this scenario its "j_id0:theForm:thePageBlock:theSection".

If you have not broken the chain while referencing the id in getElementById,  both approaches will work. Its a mater of convenience what you want to use and how much you want to figure out

```
<apex:form id="theForm">
    <apex:pageBlock id="thePageBlock" >
        <apex:pageBlockSection id="theSection"> 
             <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="theSectionItem">
                 <p>The full DOM ID resembles something like this:<br/>
                j_id0:theForm:thePageBlock:theSection:theSectionItem</p>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:outputPanel layout="block" styleClass="clicker"
                onclick="alert('{!$Component.theSectionItem}');">
                First click here
            </apex:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes that kind the code requires maintenance if you add element in the hierarchy.

Better, use `getElementbyClassName()` approach, instead of `getElementById()`.

```
<apex:inputField value="{!cust.Name}" styleClass="myElement"/>
```

Javascript

```
var form1 = document.getElementById('{!$Component.form1}');
var elements = form1.getElementsByClassName('myElement');
```

You could loop through the elements and update accordingly.

If there are any elements (table, div etc.) in between `form` and `field`, it will not create any issue. Only thing, you need to provide identifiable `styleClass` name

Also, you can explore `document.getElementsByClassName('myElement')`